# adsbygoogle.push(); 0 how to repush Google Ads

Tags: javascript, ajax, adsense

I have an Ajax site and I would like to reload the footer banner on the site each time that a user clicks a link on our website.

I thought that byy adding

```
adsbygoogle.push();
```

it would work, but all that seems to do in our ajax site is cause the page to load as normal and stop the ajax from working.

is there an issue with this function or is there another way to request new ads - and tell google the user has requested another page.

I have tried to follow https://support.google.com/dfp_sb/answer/3058726?hl=en

but the page is a bit lakelaster as it does not tell the reader where I need to place My ad code.

so this is what my page kinda looks like

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var googletag = googletag || {};
      googletag.cmd = googletag.cmd || [];
      (function() {
        var gads = document.createElement("script");
        gads.async = true;
        gads.type = "text/javascript";
       var useSSL = "https:" == document.location.protocol;
       gads.src = (useSSL ? "https:" : "http:") +
       "//www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js";
       var node = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
       node.parentNode.insertBefore(gads, node);
     })();
  </script>
</head>

<body>
   <!-- **Blocked ad for testing** Footer
    <ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:block;width:970px;height:250px; margin: 0 auto;" data-ad-client="ca-pub-4999865903647931" data-ad-slot="9664429631"></ins>
<script>
 (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>-->





<div id="div-gpt-ad-1327312723268-0" style="width:728px; height:90px;">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    var slot1 = googletag.defineSlot("/9664429631/Refresh_Example", [970, 250],
    "div-gpt-ad-1327312723268-0").addService(googletag.pubads());
    googletag.enableServices();
    googletag.display("div-gpt-ad-1327312723268-0");
    setInterval(function(){googletag.pubads().refresh([slot1]);}, 30000);
    });
  </script>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```